# Convert Date to Timestamp in Scala

Tags: java, scala, date, timestamp

In Scala, I am converting Date to Timestamp. I am currently doing this with:

```
val date = new java.util.Date()
new java.sql.Timestamp(new org.joda.time.DateTime(date).getMillis)
```

Is there a slicker way of doing this? Java-informed responses would also be relevant.

Answer (score 16):

Why not something as simple as using [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())?

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime)
```

You don't need Joda time for this. Scala isn't really relevant here, unless you need an implicit conversion:

```
//import once, use everywhere
implicit def date2timestamp(date: java.util.Date) = 
    new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime)

val date = new java.util.Date

//conversion happens implicitly
val timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp = date
```

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to even construct a Date object you could simply use this:

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

I would think this would be a tiny bit more efficient than using a new Date().  But if you already have a date object you want to get the date from this will work for you.

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(data.getTime())
```